# GetOpenFileName() usada com personificação de usuário

Tags: c, c++, segurança, services, winapi

Tenho um processo que necessita de privilégios de SISTEMA e para isso é lançado por um serviço. Quando esse processo executa a função [GetOpenFileName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms646927(v=vs.85).aspx) para abrir uma caixa de diálogo de selecionar arquivos, recebo uma mensagem de erro dizendo

> C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop não está disponível.

As pastas Desktop, Meus Documentos etc, quando seleciono-as na caixa de diálogo, estão associadas à conta do SISTEMA. Isso acontece porque o processo está rodando com privilégios de SISTEMA. Certo.

Tentei solucionar esse problema personificando a aplicação com a função [ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/aa378612(v=vs.85).aspx), mas a caixa de diálogo da função [GetOpenFileName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms646927(v=vs.85).aspx) continua associada à conta do sistema e exibindo as mesmas mensagens de erro.

Já tentei também com a nova caixa de diálogo da API, a [Common Item Dialog,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913(v=vs.85).aspx) mas acontece o mesmo. O estranho é que, se o processo está personificado como usuário, a função [GetUserName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms724432(v=vs.85).aspx) retorna o nome correto do usuário personificado.

Qual pode ser a razão disso?

Answer (score 1):

Serviços não tem acesso interativo com desktop por default. Acredito que o mesmo deva ser criado com um atributo específico para que seja permitido.
Tente pesquisar sobre SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS.

Este help deve esclarecer as restrições e meios de implementar a solução:
[Interactive Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: O serviço já está com servicetype SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS | SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS. Não funciona.
A propósito, não sei se fui claro na pergunta, mas o serviço é usado apenas para executar outro processo. Esse processo é executado com privilégios do SISTEMA (porque é necessário para executar algumas funções). Eu personifico os privilégios de usuário dentro do próprio processo, porém a função GetOpenFileName() continua associando à conta do sistema.

Comment: Você está criando o serviço com estas flags SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS | SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS?

Comment: Sim!

Como já mencionei acima.